# pattern matching in scala: Why can I match undefined variables?

Tags: scala, recursion, pattern-matching, abstract-class

I just started learing scala and found a piece of code, thats works just fine, but I just don't get why...

```
  sealed abstract class Nat

  case class Zero() extends Nat

  case class Succ(n: Nat) extends Nat

  def add(n: Nat, m: Nat): Nat = {
    n match  {
    case Zero() => m
    case Succ(prev) => add(prev, Succ(m))
    }
  }
```

The members of Nat and Zero are defined in an extra file (and used later on) like this:

```
 val zero = Zero()
 val one = Succ(zero)
 val two = Succ(one)
 val three = Succ(Succ(one))
 val four = Succ(Succ(two))
```

My question now is: In the second case 'prev' never got defined. What happens here? The math behind is clear for me, (like n+m == (n-1)+(m+1), repeat until n==Zero()). Ok so far. But all that is defined is Succ() and not a kind of Prev()?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, `prev` is declared in the case statement, here:

`case Succ(prev) => add(prev, Succ(m))`

when you are typing `case Succ(prev) ...` you are using pattern matching, and saying: if `n` is of type `Succ` and we call its `n` parameter `prev`, then return `add(...)`

so basically you are naming the n parameter of Succ class as prev to use it after the arrow `=>`

This Scala feature can even be use with regex where you capture groups that will be put into the variables you define.

More info on the docs: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 3):

Scala gives you concise syntax so instead of having to write out something like

```
if (n.isInstanceOf[Succ]) {
  val x = n.asInstanceOf[Succ]
  val prev = x.n
  add(prev, ...)
}
```

we can reason at a higher level by considering the structure of data and write simply

`case Succ(prev) => add(prev, ...)`

Comment: Do you know if Scala is doing exactly that under the hood? I'm curios if that is the actual implementation...

Comment: @Selnay Yes it should be quite similar, try experimenting with `:settings -Xprint:jvm` in REPL to see what exactly expands to on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

`case class`es in scala automatically define a method called `unapply`.

Here is the [Scala 2 Doc on Case Classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/case-classes.html)

It is this `unapply` method that enables this kind of pattern matching.

If I define a case class with a member called `value`, I can extract that value by utilizing this unapply to obtain it:

```scala
case class Number( value: Int )

val valueOfNumber: Int = Number(5).value
println(valueOfNumber) // 5

// Using unapply

val testNumber: Number = Number(200)
val Number(numberValue) = testNumber
println(numberValue) // 200
```

When you do `case Succ(prev) => add(prev, Succ(m))` you are extracting the value `n` of `Succ` as `prev` by matching on the type signatures of the `unapply` method.

Hence, `prev` is defined, it is the value, `n`, contained by the matched `Succ`